# Response message:Non HTTP response message: unknown protocol

Tags: jmeter

Could anyone please help me to understand the below issue or share any references to resolve

I am getting below error message when going to save my test plan:

```
Couldn't save test plan to file: C:\Windows\System32\View Results Tree.jmx C:\Windows\System32\View Results Tree.jmx (Access is denied)
```

While running the result by adding listener .i am getting the below error.

```
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException Response message:Non HTTP response message: unknown protocol:
```

Comment: Did you run it as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

1. The user you're running JMeter from doesn't have write access to `C:\Windows\System32\` folder, you need to choose another location to save your test plan, for example into your [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory). If you have to store the .jmx test plan under `C:\Windows\System32` folder consider [running JMeter as administrator](https://www.techspot.com/guides/1718-run-as-administrator-explained/)
2. The error indicates misconfiguration of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler,  you need to use one of the following protocols:

   - `http` - for [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP)
   - `https` - for [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https)
   - `file` - for reading a local file

example configuration:

[image]

If you're uncertain regarding the HTTP Request sampler(s) configuration you can consider recording the test scenario using your browser either using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

[Non HTTP response message: unknown protocol][1]

1. include the https in the textbook , if its http you can leave it blank
2. write the url in the server name

Please see image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqFa7.png